# maths and 2 decimal places inUITextfield

Tags: iphone, math

**here is my code I have 3 UITextfields c, d and e and a button to calculate and display the result into a UITextfield called result but I can't get the result to display 2 decimal places.**

```
func getRootValue() {
        if let cText = cValue.text, let dText = dValue.text {
        if let doubleC = Double(cText), let doubleD = Double(dText) {
            let theSquare = sqrt((doubleC * doubleC) + (doubleD * doubleD))
            rootValue.text = "\(theSquare)"
            eValue.text = String(Double(eValue.text!)!)
            myResult = String(Double(rootValue.text!)! *      Double(eValue.text!)! * 2)
           roofArea.text = String(Double(rootValue.text!)! * Double(eValue.text!)! * 2)
            roofArea.text = (NSString(format:"%.2f")) as String
           }
    }
}
```

The result is 0.00 so ive finally got 2 decimal places but its not displaying the actual calculation can anyone give me some help

Comment: "The result is 0.00": Could you check which line produces 0? For instace, what's the value of theSquare, doubleC, doubleD, etc.

Comment: Hi Larme these values doubleC and DoubleD are entered into the appropriate UITextfields by the user- if I remove the line of code roofArea.text = (NSString(format:"%.2f")) as String I get the correct result but its 6 decimal places

Comment: `NSString(format:"%.2f")` You used the place holder `%f` with "options `%.2f`, but where did you set the value for the placeholder? Instead you should do `let calculated = Double(rootValue.text!)! * Double(eValue.text!)! * 2)`, then `roofArea.text = (NSString(format:"%.2f", calculated)) as String` But you code is messy anyway.

Comment: Yea I expect it is messy as I am learning as I code not the best way, but thanks for your help though basically I am trying to enter three Values into textfields then hit a calculate button-this value is then passed to another ViewController to do more calculations- can I send you my code for this page to have a look :)

Comment: Here it is - Ive probably made a ton of mistakes but it kind of works.

Comment: seems I can't send that many characters in here